# How to open php form based on condition If else method

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to open the different form based on the result of two variable 'Type'and "facility".But in my code whenever i click on the view button  it always opens the Form1.php irrespective of the condition on that record.I checked my code but could not find out my mistake.Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 <?php 
    $type =$result->type;
    $facility =$result->facility;
    if ($facility =='C1' or $facility =='C2' or $facility =='C3' OR $facility ='C4' OR $facility =='C5'){
    $formid='FORM1.php'; 
    
    } elseif(($type =='T1' OR $type =='T2' OR $type =='T3') AND ($facility =='C6' or $facility =='C7' or $facility =='C8' OR $facility =='C9') ){
    $formid='FORM2.php';
    
    } elseif(($type =='T4' or $type =='T5' )AND ($facility =='C6' or $facility =='C7' or $facility =='C8' OR $facility =='C9') ){
    $formid='FORM3.php';
                                            
    }else{
    $formid='nothing.php';
    }   
                 
     ?>
    <a  onclick="window.open('<?php echo $formid?>?sampleid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->sampleid);?>','_blank','height=700,width=1200 top=200 left=350,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=0, scrollbars=no')"><button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i> VIEW</button>
```

Comment: `$facility = 'C4' ` should be `$facility == 'C4' ` Otherwise it assigns c4 to facility variable  Thats why first statement is always true.

Comment: This would be way better with a look-up table of some kind, or at the very least a function which returns the correct form to use. This code is dizzying. It's also odd that some of your file names are ALL CAPS and others are all lower case.

Comment: I agree with @tadman Or you can use arrays instead of table if you don't want to use table. just create array with your values and use `in_array()` function. That would be good for scaling also.

Comment: Do you really need a special pop-up window? From a usability perspective those are extraordinarily annoying and generate a lot of resentment. Just open in a new tab if you must with `target="_blank"`. Don't pop windows, especially those with arbitrary sizes that might not be possible on the user's computer and/or device.

Comment: `in_array($facility, ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5])` will spare you from a kilometer of code.